# Not able to show the image according to condition in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working in Ionic project and I am showing the user profile image in Ionic. When the user is login, the original profile image will show otherwise the demo image will show but the problem is that It is not showing the demo image when the user is not login.

This is my **app.html**:

```
<ion-col col-4>
    <img class="imgsection12" src="{{this.userpimage ? 'assets/imgs/hipster-man.jpg' : 'http://beegoodhoney.in/uploads/user/'+this.userpimage}}" />
</ion-col>
```

In this html, I have used the condition that if the `this.userpimage` is set, it will show the original profile image otherwise it will show the demo image but the problem is that it is not showing=ng the demo image when the user is not login.

This is my **app.component.ts**:

```
userpimage;
this.storage.get("IMAGE2").then((val2) =>
{
  if(val2)
  {
    this.userpimage = val2;
    console.log(this.userpimage);
  }
});
```

When I console the value, it is showing the image name.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

HTML:

```
<ion-col col-4>
    <img class="imgsection12" [src]="profileImage" />
</ion-col>
```

Component.ts:

```
public profileImage = './assets/imgs/hipster-man.jpg';
userpimage;
this.storage.get("IMAGE2").then((val2) =>
{
  if(val2)
  {
    this.userpimage = val2;
    console.log(this.userpimage);
    this.profileImage = `http://beegoodhoney.in/uploads/user/${this.userpimage}`;
  }
});
```

That way later when you logout you can set the `profileImage` variable to something else if you want, like back to `'./assets/imgs/hipster-man.jpg';` for example.

Comment: Without condition it is showing the image but In your answer it is always showing the first image means first image only.

Comment: Looks like you have the conditions around the wrong way, I just copied your code above, if `userpimage` is true shouldn't you do `'http://beegoodhoney.in/uploads/user/'+ userpimage` instead, ternary goes `condition ? 'if true : 'else'`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yes, it is working but can you help me like when I click the logout it is still showing the profile image and when I reload after that it will show the default image.

Comment: Might be better to just make the image src a variable instead then and set it to what you want based on login / logout events